# Select default schema for MS SQL

Tags: yii2

I need to configure Yii2 to work with Microsoft SQL server.

The db configuration file (db.php) is something like this

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',

'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=192.168.77.111;Database=xyz',
'username' => 'xy',
'password' => 'xyz',
```

This works only if i add before the table name in the tableName() function inside all models the correct schema name.
For example:

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%xyzschema.users}}';
}
```

How can i set the db configuration so xyzschema is always added when connecting to the table?
I tried with tablePrefix and schemaMap with defaultSchema but it doesn't work

The error returned is

```
Invalid object name 'users'.
```

or

```
Invalid object name 'xyzschema.users'.
```

If i add tablePrefix to db.php

**Update:** The `defaultSchema` property inside connection's `schemaMap/Schema` config array gets ingored

Comment: I'm not PHP but I guess you need to include the equivilent of "Initial Catalog" in your connection string.

Comment: I don't know MS SQL server, it's something to set inside that and not inside the application configuration?

Comment: Yii uses PHP PDO drivers to connect to different databases for MSSQL see [**`here`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)  so do you have the drivers installed, and you are on which `OS`?

Comment: I'm on windows with XAMPP, by the way if i add to a single table like users the schema like xyzschema.users it works, so i just need to add something like that on the connection so i can get gii and auth to work

Comment: On Windows, you should use SqlSrv, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from [**`Microsoft:`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) and do set `'emulatePrepare' => false,` in your connection options

Comment: see this [**`link`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/192/config-use-ms-sql-server-2005-2008/#c10847) in the comments section how to configure the string for `dsn`

Comment: You said that you tried setting the `Connection` `tablePrefix` property like this: `'tablePrefix' => 'xyzschema.'` but it didn't work, what error did you get? I might be wrong but the resulting SQL should be the same that what you get changing the `tableName` method to return `{{%xyzschema.users}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case i solved changing the schema to the standard "dbo" for each table.